# Test api keys for soundcloud

Tags: android, ios, soundcloud

I am trying to create a cross platform music playback application through soundcloud API and for the initial stages of development and testing I need a soundcloud API key but the registration process states it takes a month for the app to get registered and that will really delay our process.

Is there a way to get test api keys for development instantly even if they are active for a short duration (2-3 months)?

Comment: Im also looking for a test API Key. I dont understand why it takes soundcloud such a long time. Whats even more dissapointing is having to wait for a month then they tell you that your App did not qualify. And then you have to wait for another month